# How to update a model field using templates?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a project that allows users to register, but the model contains a verified field and only admin can change it. User can log in only when verified = True. Also, I need to implement that once a user is verified, he gets notified through a mail. Is there a way to connect the mail url to the verified field? If it can be done through templates, How? I want to redirect to mail url as soon as admin updates the verified field.

Comment: This is far too vague. And what does "through templates" mean? You can't make changes to the database without a URL and a view.

Comment: It meant that can I create a view and render template and then make changes to the field.

Comment: Of course you can. I don't understand what the question is.